# Scrapy: Fetch HTML class as string and/or int?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

For educative purposes I've been creating a spider to fetch data from a HTML-based marketplace. I managed to fetch all the text based data I need, however, I need to fetch the itemID, the data-mins-elapsed, the item quality and item trait. These items are not text based, but they are HTML classes and such.

- The ItemID is a unique ID for each item. In the HTML code of the website it can be found under: *(I need the number "319842588", this number is unique to each item)*

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer" data-on-click-link="/pc/Trade/Detail/319842588" data-on-click-link-action="NewWindow" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">
```

- The data-mins-elapsed keeps track of when the item has been posted. This number will change everytime you refresh the webpage as time goes by. It can be found under: *(I need the number "3", this number will change constantly)*

```
<td class="bold hidden-xs" data-mins-elapsed="3">Now</td>
```

- The itemquality is the quality of a certain item. In the HTML code of the website it can be found under: *(I need the "superior", the quality is unique to each item)*

```
<img class="trade-item-icon item-quality-superior"
     alt="Icon"
     src="/Content/icons/bow.png"
            data-trait="Infused"
           />
```

- The itemtrait is the trait of a certain item. In the HTML code of the website it can be found under: *(I need the "Infused", the trait is unique to each item)*

```
<img class="trade-item-icon item-quality-superior"
     alt="Icon"
     src="/Content/icons/bow.png"
            data-trait="Infused"
           />
```

How do I build a XPATH or something similar to fetch these numbers?

Website link: https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/SearchResult?SearchType=Sell&ItemID=10052&ItemNamePattern=Briarheart+Bow&IsChampionPoint=true&LevelMin=160&LevelMax=&ItemCategory1ID=&ItemCategory2ID=&ItemCategory3ID=&ItemQualityID=&ItemTraitID=3&PriceMin=&PriceMax=25000

**Part of the relevant HTML code**

*This includes the HTML for each product, each product is listed in a TR with tha class "cursor-pointer"*

```
<table class="trade-list-table max-width">
    <thead>
     ...
    </thead>

        <tr class="cursor-pointer" data-on-click-link="/pc/Trade/Detail/319836098"
            data-on-click-link-action="NewWindow" data-toggle="tooltip">
            <td>
               <img class="trade-item-icon item-quality-superior"alt="Icon"
     src="/Content/icons/bow.png"data-trait="Infused"/>
             <div class="item-quality-superior">
             Briarheart Bow
                </div>
                <div>
                Level:
                <img class="small-icon" src="/Content/icons/championPoint.png" />
                160
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
            ...
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
            ...
            </td>
            <td class="gold-amount bold">
            ...
            </td>
            <td class="bold hidden-xs" data-mins-elapsed="15"></td>
        </tr>
```

**Spider file**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import os
import csv

class TTCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ttc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["eu.tamrieltradecentre.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/SearchResult?ItemID=10052&SearchType=Sell&ItemNamePattern=Briarheart+Bow&ItemCategory1ID=&ItemCategory2ID=&ItemCategory3ID=&ItemTraitID=3&ItemQualityID=&IsChampionPoint=true&IsChampionPoint=false&LevelMin=160&LevelMax=&MasterWritVoucherMin=&MasterWritVoucherMax=&AmountMin=&AmountMax=&PriceMin=&PriceMax=25000']

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text=keyword["keyword"]
                url="https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/{0}".format(search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text}) 

    def parse(self, response):
         containers = response.css('.cursor-pointer')
         for container in containers:

             #Defining the XPAths
             XPATH_ITEM_NAME = ".//td[1]//div[1]//text()"
             XPATH_ITEM_LEVEL = ".//td[1]//div[2]//text()"
             XPATH_ITEM_LOCATION = ".//td[3]//div[1]//text()" 
             XPATH_ITEM_TRADER = ".//td[3]//div[2]//text()"  
             XPATH_ITEM_PRICE = ".//td[4]//text()[2]" 
             XPATH_ITEM_QUANTITY = ".//td[4]//text()[4]"    
             XPATH_ITEM_LASTSEEN = "Help me plis :3" 
             XPATH_ITEM_ITEMID = "Help me plis :3"
             XPATH_ITEM_QUALITY = "Help me plis :3" 
             XPATH_ITEM_TRAIT = "Help me plis :3"             

             #Extracting from list
             raw_item_name = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_NAME).extract()
             raw_item_level = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_LEVEL).extract()
             raw_item_location = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_LOCATION).extract()  
             raw_item_trader = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_TRADER).extract()             
             raw_item_price = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_PRICE).extract() 
             raw_item_quantity = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_QUANTITY).extract()              
             raw_item_lastseen = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_LASTSEEN).extract() 
             raw_item_itemid = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_ITEMID).extract() 
             raw_item_quality = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_QUALITY).extract()
             raw_item_trait = container.xpath(XPATH_ITEM_TRAIT).extract()             

             #Cleaning the data
             item_name = ''.join(raw_item_name).strip() if raw_item_name else None
             item_level = ''.join(raw_item_level).replace('Level:','').strip() if raw_item_level else None             
             item_location = ''.join(raw_item_location).strip() if raw_item_location else None
             item_trader = ''.join(raw_item_trader).strip() if raw_item_trader else None
             item_price = ''.join(raw_item_price).strip() if raw_item_price else None
             item_quantity = ''.join(raw_item_quantity).strip() if raw_item_quantity else None   
             item_lastseen = ''.join(raw_item_lastseen).strip() if raw_item_lastseen else None
             item_itemid = ''.join(raw_item_itemid).strip() if raw_item_itemid else None    
             item_quality = ''.join(raw_item_quality).strip() if raw_item_quality else None             
             item_trait = ''.join(raw_item_trait).strip() if raw_item_trait else None             

             yield {
                'item_name':item_name,
                'item_level':item_level, 
                'item_location':item_location, 
                'item_trader':item_trader, 
                'item_price':item_price,                
                'item_quantity':item_quantity, 
                'item_lastseen':item_lastseen,  
                'item_itemid':item_itemid,                
                'item_quality':item_quality,                
                'item_trait':item_trait,               
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in `.re_first()` to match regular expression for `ItemID`:

```
ItemID = container.xpath('./@data-on-click-link').re_first(r'(\d+)$') # same code for ItemQuality 
ItemTrait = container.xpath('.//img[@data-trait]/@data-trait').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't be asking such questions, a simple google search should suffice. Nonetheless all you need is way to access data available in the attributes of a HTML Node. The way is using `@` as a prefix to attribute name. e.g: for accessing class attribute you would use `div/@class`.

For your problem I could suggest a XPath for one of your item, you should be able to take on from that.

XPATH_ITEM_LASTSEEN = ".//td[4]/@data-mins-elapsed"

Also, for getting `319842588` out of `data-on-click-link="/pc/Trade/Detail/319842588"`, you can use XPATH similar to above in addition to python's inbuilt functions like `replace()` or `split()` to get the desired data. for example:
suppose you have -

```
x = "/pc/Trade/Detail/319842588" 
# you could do something like
x = x.replace('/pc/Trade/Detail/','') OR x = x.split('/')[-1]
```

Hope that helps.
Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @jenis Sakhiya. Your solution seems to work as well! I have tried to google for a solution, but I suppose I've been googling using the wrong keywords..